# Storing comments & special characters or RTF in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

I have a relatively simple question.

I'm designing a commenting system operating via PHP --> mysql, and when I submit a comment with a special character in it, ie. a quotation mark [']... it screws up the query.

Obviously I have to strip these to prevent injection and whatnot, but what is the easiest way to parse back and forth between submitting quotes and other special characters like line breaks into a database and then parsing it so its displayed the way it was originally written? I.e. I can place a paragraph a couple lines down..

.

Down here. The database is storing those extra line breaks. Are there built in PHP parsers for this or do I have to write one somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP Extension `PDO` does this well, I have re made PDO and made it much simpler to use cause it can be kind of complex, but tutorials can be found and I learned it all in a day or so.

If you want to get started with PDO you will want to make a connection like so:

```
$handler = new PDO("mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DATABASE_NAME", DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD);
```

And using that, the HOST can be example `localhost`, DATABASE_NAME is obvious, username and password I'm sure that you can figure out!

If you want to use a query from a `$_GET['']` array you can do this by doing the following:

```
$query = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:user, :pass);
$query->execute(array( 
  ':user' => $_GET['username'],
  ':pass' => $_GET['password']
));
```

What happens here is the username and password is safely given to the query, and then executed in the `$query->execute` statement; no matter if there is a `'` or a `"` in the URL.

If you want to read more on the PDO library, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Awesome, I'll check it out. I have been hesitant to learn PDO but everyone seems to think/say it's better than mysqli.

Comment: It's muuuuuuuuuuuuuuuch better than MySQLi, honestly I dont get how anyone is still learning it cause it make everything much easier, there are good YouTube tutorials on it and it's really simple. Hope I helped out @Vranvs

Comment: **Note** - There are sanitisation methods for MySQLi, but not sure what they are, you could probably look them up.